# How to load data automatically in particular field without page reloading in ASP.net mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

[Customer Parent View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOsO.jpg)

Hi This is my Parent View **Customer**.I have one add button near to **Area** if i enter the CustomerName AddressType, street, location and then select the area.Suppose if area is not in the list means i have to add that. so i click that add button it will open **AreaPartial** view as popup window.

[Area Partial View Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzYo2.jpg)

After i enter the details and click the  create button it will save the data in db and it shows the same popup window when it was close means when i click x mark[which is in the pop up window right top corner ) . Now all are working fine.

Now my issue is  after i close the popup window using the X mark( which is in the pop up window right top corner) it didn't load the value which i recently added in the area field. Once i refresh the whole customer view(parent view) and click the Area field the value is loaded.

This is my issue when i close the popup window the value which i recently added have to load automatically in the **Area** Field of Customer Parent view. How to do this task.

**My Model CustomerView Model **
In this model  it contain both partial view properties and Parent view properties.
    public System.Guid customerID{get;set;}
    public string CustomerName{get;set;}
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public Nullable AreaID { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public Nullable CityID{ get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }

**My Controller code to save the data which is entered in the partial view pop-up window**

```
  public ActionResult AreaPartialView()
  {
   ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName");
   return View("AreaPartialView");
 }
 [HttpPost]

  public ActionResult AddAreaInfo(CustomerViewModel objareaVM)
  {
    var objAreaID = Guid.NewGuid();
    ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName", objareaVM.CityID);

  var ObjArea = new Area()
    {
        AreaID =objAreaID,
        DisplayName = objareaVM.Area,
        PrintName = objareaVM.Area,
        CityID = objareaVM.CityID,
        IsActive = true,
        IsDeleted = false,
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
        EditedDate = DateTime.Now,
        LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now,
        RowID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        OfflineMode = false,
        OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid()
    };

    db.Areas.Add(ObjArea);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ModelState.Clear();

    return Json("Customer", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

**My Parent View Area Field**

```
  <div id="Area">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "control-label"})
  @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
  <button id="AddArea">Area</button>
  <div id="AddAreaNew"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**My j-query code to display the area partial view as popup window once the add button is clicked**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#AddArea").click(function () {
      $('#AddAreaNew').dialog("open");
       });
      $(function () {
        $('#AddAreaNew').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       width: 400,
       height: 500,
       resizable: false,
       title: 'Add Area',
       modal: true,
       open: function (event, ui) {
           $(this).load("@Url.Action("AreaPartialView", "Customer")");
       },
       buttons: {
           "Close": function () {
               $(this).dialog("close");
           }
       }
   });
   });
```

**My Partial View code**

```
   @Html.Label("Area" , new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,id ="AreaName"})
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Area)


   @Html.Label("City")        
   @Html.DropDownList("CityID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control " })


  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.4-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function SaveArea() {
    debugger;
    var Area = $("#AreaName").val();
    var CityID = $("#CityID").val();
    alert(Area);
    var AreaAdd = { "Area": '' +Area + '', "CityID": CityID };
    $.post("/Customer/AddAreaInfo", AreaAdd,
    function (data) { if (data == 0) { location = location.href; } }, 'json').success(function (data) {
        alert("sucess");
        window.close();
    });
}
```

All are working fine if i click the button the partial view open as pop-up window and after enter the details and click the create button it saves the data in db too but it does not load the value automatically after closing the pop-up window. once refresh the whole parent view the value will be load automatically. please any one help to solve this issue..

Advance thanks..

Comment: In the ajax call that saves the new area, you need to update the `<select>` element by adding an new `<option>` element to it.

Comment: please can you define me the answer with detail description stephen..

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but your code is a mess and I don't even know where to begin. But something like `$.post("/Customer/AddAreaInfo", AreaAdd, function(data) { $(yourAreaDropdown).append($('<option><option>').val(data).text(Area));` and change the server method to `return Json(objAreaID); });`

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenient i will give the appropriate names for each code.

Comment: stephen one doubt why we  return the Id in json??

Comment: Because you have create a new `Area` and assigned its `ID` in the controller. Your client does not know what that is so you need to return it back to the controller and create a new option with `value="xxx"` where `xxx` is the ID so when you select it, the ID of the `Area` will be posted. But please do not use `Guid`. Change all your `ID` fields to `int` and use auto-incremented database keys.

Comment: ok lets i have a try and if i got any issue means i will post it again

Comment: Stephen i have one another doubt shall i ask that

Comment: What doubt do you have?

Comment: Stephen i did as per you said its working. first i have to say thanks for that . Then my doubt is if i click the add button near to area field and add the area and close the pop-up window . Now again i have to add the new area means i click the add button again.But if i click the  add button it not working it doesn't open the pop-up window. This is the issue.

Comment: If you referring to the button with `<button id="AddArea">Area</button>`, then you need to use event delegation (using the `.on(event, selector, function)` method).